# How to use ANativeWindow_setBuffersDataSpace in NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I use ANativeWindow_setBuffersDataSpace in NDK,it prompts no error.But I build the project,the logcat shows that
`"undefined reference to ANativeWindow_setBuffersDataSpace'clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 " . However I can find this API in native_window.h "__INTRODUCED_IN(28);"and I set minsdk 28.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `libnativewindow.so` to linked libraries, e.g. if you use CMake:

```
add_library(MainActivity SHARED MainActivity.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MainActivity
        android
        native_app_glue
        EGL
        GLESv1_CM
        nativewindow
        )
```

Comment: Welcome. Now you can choose the answer like correct one.